# Why doesn't removing from a TreeSet with a custom comparator remove a larger set of items?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, java-11, treeset

Using both Java 8 and Java 11, consider the following [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a [`String::compareToIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) comparator:

```
final Set<String> languages = new TreeSet<>(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
languages.add("java");
languages.add("c++");
languages.add("python");

System.out.println(languages);                 // [c++, java, python]
```

When I try to remove the exact elements present in the `TreeSet`, it works: all of those specified are removed:

```
languages.removeAll(Arrays.asList("PYTHON", "C++"));

System.out.println(languages);                 // [java]
```

However, if I try to remove instead **more** than is present in the [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), the call doesn't remove anything at all (this is not a subsequent call but called instead of the snippet above):

```
languages.removeAll(Arrays.asList("PYTHON", "C++", "LISP"));

System.out.println(languages);                 // [c++, java, python]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it behave this way?

Edit: `String::compareToIgnoreCase` is a valid comparator:

```
(l, r) -> l.compareToIgnoreCase(r)
```

Comment: Related bug entry: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180409 (TreeSet removeAll inconsistent behaviour with String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

Comment: A closely related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671903/the-hashsett-removeall-method-is-surprisingly-slow).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123178/unintuitive-behavior-of-removeall-method-in-sets/18124076

Comment: I wonder how you could use the `TreeSet(comparator)`-constructor without shooting yourself in the foot like that. `compareTo` inconsistent with `equals` is highly discouraged precisely because it makes Collections do nonsensical things, yet `TreeSet(comparator)` makes you more or less redefine one without the other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the javadoc of [removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractSet.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)):

> This implementation determines which is the smaller of this set and the specified collection, by invoking the size method on each. If this set has fewer elements, then the implementation iterates over this set, checking each element returned by the iterator in turn to see if it is contained in the specified collection. If it is so contained, it is removed from this set with the iterator's remove method. If the specified collection has fewer elements, then the implementation iterates over the specified collection, removing from this set each element returned by the iterator, using this set's remove method.

In your second experiment, you're in the first case of the javadoc. So it iterates over "java", "c++", etc. and checks if they're contained in the Set returned by `Set.of("PYTHON", "C++")`. They're not, so they're not removed.
Use another TreeSet using the same comparator as argument, and it should work fine.
Using two different Set implementations, one using `equals()`, and the other one using a comparator, is a dangerous thing to do indeed.

Note that there is a bug opened about this: [[JDK-8180409] TreeSet removeAll inconsistent behaviour with String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180409).

Comment: Do you mean when both sets would have the same characteristics, it works?

`final Set<String> subLanguages = new TreeSet<>(String::compareToIgnoreCase);`
`subLanguages.addAll(Arrays.asList("PYTHON", "C++", "LISP"));`
`languages.removeAll(subLanguages);`

Comment: You're in the case "If this set has fewer elements", described by the javadoc. The other case being "If the specified collection has fewer elements".

Comment: This answer is right, but it is very unintuitive behavior. It feels like a flaw in the design of `TreeSet`.

Comment: I agree, but I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Unless someone can find a case use for this anomally I would expect it could be fixed with minimal repercussions to existing code.

Comment: Finally, is it a bug or just a very unintuitive feature with correctly documented behavior?

Comment: It's both: it's a very unintuitive behavior that is correctly documented, but, being unintuitive and deceiving, it's also a design bug that might, some day, be fixed.